# interpretation of an execution plan with limit and order by

Tags: postgresql, sql-execution-plan

I have a test1 table which contains 20'000'000 tuples. I make a request on this table with the order by clause. The number of returned tuples is limited to 10.
I do not understand why in the execution plan there are less than 20'000'000 of tuples treated whereas with order by clause it should parse the whole table.

```
demo=# explain select content from test1 order by content limit 10;
 Limit  (cost=451329.69..451330.85 rows=10 width=33)
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=451329.69..2395909.82 rows=16666666 width=33)
         Workers Planned: 2
         ->  Sort  (cost=450329.66..471163.00 rows=8333333 width=33)
               Sort Key: content
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on test1  (cost=0.00..270249.33 rows=8333333 width=33)
 JIT:
   Functions: 3
   Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
(9 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

[As explained in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html) the number of rows reported in a "simple" explain output is an **estimate**.

So the total number of rows in that table is estimated to 16666666  (this can be seen in the Gather Merge node)

Postgres chose to do a Parallel Seq Scan on the table to read all rows. A simple `explain` (without any further options) does not show details about the parallel part. But the estimated number of rows shown in the `Parallel Seq Scan` node is exactly half of the total number of rows estimated for the table. So you can assume the planner will use two thread to do the parallel scan.

I am pretty sure that if you run `explain (analyze) select ...` you will see the number of parallel workers reported to be 2. Then you will also see the **real** number of rows each worker processed (most likely exactly 100000)

Answer (score 0):

It is using a parallel plan, so it divvies the 20,000,000 rows three ways (one leader plus 2 works).  However, the data is divvied up by blocks, not by individuals rows, so the estimated number of rows is based on a fudge factor that assumes someone is going to get a disproportionate amount of them.

At the merge step, it is counting the tuples it thinks will get passed up by the workers, but is (apparently, I have not dug into the source code for this) not counting the rows that the leader itself is expected to be delivering.

Plans are a lot easier to interpret if you disable parallelization first, `set max_parallel_workers_per_gather TO 0;`.  Unless parallelization is the very thing you are currently investigating, of course.